# Javascript regex pattern without for money values without currency

Tags: javascript, regex

I was looking for a javascript regex pattern that will allow inserting or registering these type of amount

```
5
5.1
5.10
5
500,000
500,000.1
500,000.10
```

but these numbers should not be lesser than 0. I managed to find pattern but I want to omit the "$". All I want is numbers,commas,and dots only

```
var x = 5000;
var a = "5,000,000"
var y = "$5,,,000,000"
var z = "500,000"
var c = "c231"
console.log(x," Valid", /^\$?\d+(,\d{3})*(\.\d*)?$/.test(x))
console.log(a," Valid", /^\$?\d+(,\d{3})*(\.\d*)?$/.test(a))
console.log(y," Valid", /^\$?\d+(,\d{3})*(\.\d*)?$/.test(y))
console.log(z," Valid", /^\$?\d+(,\d{3})*(\.\d*)?$/.test(z))
console.log(c," Valid", /^\$?\d+(,\d{3})*(\.\d*)?$/.test(c))
```

Comment: Remove \$? From RegEx

Comment: New RegEx will be    /^\d+(,\d{3})*(\.\d*)?$/

Comment: Did my answer help? Consider accepting it if it did.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `\$?`

`/^\d+(,\d{3})*(\.\d*)?$/`

```js
var x = 5000;
var a = "5,000,000"
var y = "$5,,,000,000"
var z = "500,000"
var c = "c231"
var d = "1...0.00"
var e = "..."
var f = "1.00,,,"

var validRegEx = /^\d+(,\d{3})*(\.\d*)?$/;

console.log(x," Valid", validRegEx.test(x))
console.log(a," Valid", validRegEx.test(a))
console.log(y," Valid", validRegEx.test(y))
console.log(z," Valid", validRegEx.test(z))
console.log(c," Valid", validRegEx.test(c))
console.log(d," Valid", validRegEx.test(c))
console.log(e," Valid", validRegEx.test(c))
console.log(f," Valid", validRegEx.test(c))
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my Comment on Question the new code will be

```
var x = 5000;
var a = "5,000,000"
var y = "$5,,,000,000"
var z = "500,000"
var c = "c231"
console.log(x," Valid", /^\d+(,\d{3})*(\.\d*)?$/.test(x))
console.log(a," Valid", /^\d+(,\d{3})*(\.\d*)?$/.test(a))
console.log(y," Valid", /^\d+(,\d{3})*(\.\d*)?$/.test(y))
console.log(z," Valid", /^\d+(,\d{3})*(\.\d*)?$/.test(z))
console.log(c," Valid", /^\d+(,\d{3})*(\.\d*)?$/.test(c))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
^\$?([0-9]{1,3},([0-9]{3},)*[0-9]{3}|[0-9]+)(\.[0-9][0-9])?$
```